# google map flutter plugin

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

hello I try to use google map plugin for flutter https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter

I use this exemple
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib

but in this exemple there is some page. In my application I need only one map at the launch on the app. Problem, with this exemple I didn't manage to use it at my convenience. So I try to use the minimalist example of the read.me but it's a statlesswidget, and I and can't integer Tag fonction or the map_ui.dart like the complet example. So I tried to pass this stateless in statefull but when I do this I have an error

here is what I tried to compile from the two example

---

### exemple 1 https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/google_maps_flutter

```
void main() {
  GoogleMapController.init();
  final GoogleMapOverlayController controller =
  GoogleMapOverlayController.fromSize(width: 300.0, height: 200.0);
  final Widget mapWidget = GoogleMapOverlay(controller: controller);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Google Maps demo')),
      body: MapUiBody(mapWidget, controller.mapController),
    ),
    navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[controller.overlayController],
  ));
 }
```

---

exemple 2

### https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/map_ui.dart

```
class MapUiBody extends StatefulWidget {
   final GoogleMapOverlayController controller;

   const MapUiBody(this.controller, GoogleMapController mapController);

   @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
      MapUiBodyState(controller.mapController);
  }

 class MapUiBodyState extends State<MapUiBody> {
  MapUiBodyState(this.mapController);

  final GoogleMapController mapController;

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
    );
  }
}
```

---

with this, I have an error

```
body: MapUiBody(mapWidget, controller.mapController),
```

```
mapWidget: the argument type Widget can't be assigned to the  parameter type 'GooglemapoverlayController'
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: sorry I'm a newbi :), I look for to assemble two exemple, because each of his two exemple are not what I want. One use multi page while I want only a map on screen with no page , the other exemple is OK with the map on home screen but I don't know to add fonction in this structure, statlesswidget seems to bloc add function. but when I pass it in statefullwidget I have errors

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
final GoogleMapOverlayController controller;

const MapUiBody(this.controller, GoogleMapController mapController);
```

where you pass

```
final GoogleMapOverlayController controller =
    GoogleMapOverlayController.fromSize(width: 300.0, height: 200.0);
final Widget mapWidget = GoogleMapOverlay(controller: controller);

  ...

  body: MapUiBody(mapWidget, controller.mapController),
```

where `mapWidget` is passed to `final GoogleMapOverlayController controller;` which is not a `Widget`.
`controller.mapController` is probably a `GoogleMapController` as expected by `const MapUiBody(..., GoogleMapController mapController);`
 but it seems redundant to pass that because you can get it from `controller` passed to `mapWidget` anyway.

It's not clear from your code what your intentions are.

Why do you want to pass `mapWidget`? What should happen with it in `MapUiBody`?

Comment: I think I don't understand this code. I just try to mix two exemple but each use different approch. but to be simple I just search to use this exemple in home page https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/map_ui.dart

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded to display map on home page but I can't move the map ..

```
void main() {
  GoogleMapController.init();
  final GoogleMapOverlayController controller =
  GoogleMapOverlayController.fromSize(width: 300.0, height: 200.0);
  final Widget mapWidget = GoogleMapOverlay(controller: controller);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: new Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Google Maps demo')),
  body: MapsDemo(mapWidget, controller.mapController),
),
 ));
}


 class MapsDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  MapsDemo(this.mapWidget, this.controller);

   final Widget mapWidget;
   final GoogleMapController controller;
   @override
   final GoogleMapOverlayController mapController =
    GoogleMapOverlayController.fromSize(
    width: 300.0,
height: 200.0,
options: GoogleMapOptions(
  cameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(-33.852, 151.211),
    zoom: 11.0,
  ),
  trackCameraPosition: true,
  ),
);

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MapUiBody(mapController);
  }
 }


class MapUiBody extends StatefulWidget {
  final GoogleMapOverlayController controller;

  const MapUiBody(this.controller);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>
     MapUiBodyState(controller.mapController);
  }

 class MapUiBodyState extends State<MapUiBody> {
  MapUiBodyState(this.mapController);

  final GoogleMapController mapController;
   GoogleMapOptions _options;

  @override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();
   mapController.addListener(_onMapChanged);
   _extractMapInfo();
  }

  void _onMapChanged() {
   setState(() {
    _extractMapInfo();
   });
  }

  void _extractMapInfo() {
    _options = mapController.options;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    mapController.removeListener(_onMapChanged);
   super.dispose();
   }


  Widget _mapTypeCycler() {
    final MapType nextType =
    MapType.values[(_options.mapType.index + 1) % MapType.values.length];
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('change map type to $nextType'),
      onPressed: () {
       mapController.updateMapOptions(
         GoogleMapOptions(mapType: nextType),
      );
    },
  );
}



  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Center(
        child: GoogleMapOverlay(controller: widget.controller),
      ),
    ),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[

        _mapTypeCycler(),

       ],
     ),
   ],
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: hi i have same issues in here , did you found any workaround for this issues ?

Comment: no, I gave up this map because it is too restrictive :(

Comment: so what do you use for maps in flutter ? and recomendation ?

Comment: ok looking forward to it thanks ? so is it better than google_maps_flutter ? do you ecounter any bugs from it ?

Comment: Better no, it's a different approache map view only work  in full screen, you can't add widget to interact on front of the map. Google map plugin can be cool if you have only one page with no widget who pass in front because the layer of the plugin is always on top. But the map can be resize and positionned where you want in the screen and add widget in the emplty space.